# How to boot lubuntu from a live usb on an EeeBook?

Tags: boot, live-usb, asus

Hitting "escape" at power-on gives the choice between windows boot manager or other, and "other" opens the BIOS. Hitting F2 repeatedly at power-on also brings up the BIOS.

With of without "secure boot" disabled, THERE IS NO USB OPTION.

I'm supposed to change boot options from within windows 10. In "parameters" I search for "boot", click on the result, and I can see "re-initialise" or "advanced startup". There I see "UEFI Removable Device". I select it and it boots into windows.

Another option in "boot" is "troubleshoot"/"Advanced". There I can select "Shell". I see a blue background with a message saying "select your account". There is only one and no way to select it - or to do anything except powering off the EeeBook.

Another option in "toubleshoot/advanced" is "change UEFI microprogram parameters". It says "restart to change them". I click "restart", it reboots and goes into the BIOS where there is no "boot from USB" option.

I found a new version of the bios here:
https://www.asus.com/supportonly/X205TA/HelpDesk_BIOS/
(if you need one for a different model, don't use their search, replace X250TA by your model number in the link).

I opened it with the WinFlash program and it told me it was updating the BIOS. When I went back there the BIOS looked exactly the same.

I found a discussion here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/KeyManagement/ImageSigning
Then I went to canonical's site. There's stuff about Ubuntu running on a cloud. I don't understand all this. Do I need a special - signed - iso file to bypass the problem? Are they doing this deliberatly to prevent people from installing Ubuntu?

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Can I assume no DVD either?

Comment: No DVD option in bios, no DVD drive on this machine. Not even a real hard disk in it, just what I suppose is some flash memory on the motherboard and a "One Drive" option for external storage somewhere.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, I hope someone will answer... People pay to get Windows, really? I would gladly pay to get rid of it!

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Now I'm formatting a file with the EeeBook in NTFS and I plan to copy on it all the files of a (supposedly) bootable usb stick. Can't alter bootable usb sticks because when you make them bootable they become read-only (if someone knows a way round this restriction, please tell me). But I can copy everything from a bootable usb stick to an NTFS-formatted usb stick and try to boot from that.

Comment: EVERYTHING is going wrong. Now I'm trying to download Grub2Win on the EeeBook and the download stops every 30 seconds to ask me if I want to go on!!! I've had to press enter every 30 seconds to get the thing!!! Who ever heard of such a stupid glitch?

Comment: Anyway, Grub2Win didn't function. Why am I not surprised? I've been fighting this for one week. Anyone who lives in France (because of postal costs) and who fancies the challenge, I'll send you the EeeBook by mail. If it turns out you're someone dishonest who doesn't return it, tough. I would say "good riddance" except this EeeBook was given as a present to my 6-years-old... If it wasn't for her, I would have trashed that horrible machine several days ago!

Comment: The only thing I managed was to make the BIOS display USB; The options for that are EHCI or XHCI, I read that I should select EHCI. I managed that by presenting it with a Windows usb stick. Now the usb option in the BIOS is called "Windows to go". But when I select that and reboot with one of my Ubuntu live usb sticks, the EeeBook only restarts as far as the BIOS.

Comment: Could it be that your Eeebook being 32 bit? I had similar problems when I was trying to install to Asus T100. I managed to install ubuntu on it by adding a custom bootia32.efi file to the installation media.

Comment: It has a 64 bits chip but the rest seems to be 32 bits. I tried both. The bootia32.efi I read about, but once I create a bootable usb stick it becomes read-only and even with "sudo mount -o rw,uid=1000 /dev/sdd1 /media/disk" it stays read-only. So I can't create /EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi

Comment: I tried again. No. Some people say they can run Ubuntu from a USB stick, save settings, etc... Not on my machine. The USB keys are perfectly writable until I turn them into bootable media. Then they become read-only and they stay read-only until I reformat them. Everything is going wrong.

Comment: Well I guess you are going to put that bootia32.efi to the boot USB. I managed it, but I don't remember now. I'm trying to remember and be back when I do.

Comment: Thank you very much NK.

Comment: What could be going wrong? Could my 58.5 GO usb sticks be too large? Any other suggestions, even wild ones?

Comment: I explained the things I do with my Asus T100 in a separate answer. You can try them. Just please let me know if it works :)

Comment: I guess you have tried every possible key to boot from USB by now, but, if by any chance that's not the case, maybe try repeatedly hitting Tab or F9 at start-up (it was a long time ago, so I'm not quite sure which did the trick for me).

Answer (score 0):

Installing an operating system on these older EeeBooks has always been a right pain because nothing is allowed to be "simple" anymore. That said, just because something's difficult doesn't mean it's impossible.

These are the steps you'll need to follow:

#### 1 — Configure Your BIOS

1. Make sure the netbook is off
2. Plug in the bootable USB stick with the version of Ubuntu (perhaps Xubuntu, or MATE given the hardware limitations of the device) you wish to use
3. Start the netbook and hold the <kbd>F2</kbd> button down to get into BIOS
4. Under the "Advanced" tab:
   • Select "USB Configuration"
   • Select "USB Controller Select"
   • Set this to `EHCI` ⇠ Otherwise your mouse and keyboard will never work
5. Under the "Security" tab:
   • Select "Secure Boot"
   • Select "Secure Boot Control"
   • Set to `Disabled` ⇠ Otherwise you will receive a lovely **SECURE BOOT VIOLATION** message on boot. This is because the factory security keys do not recognise Ubuntu's EFI bootloader.
6. Under the "Save & Exit" tab
   • Select "Save Changes" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> ⇠ **DO NOT CHOOSE "Save Changes and Exit"**
   • Select "Boot Override"
   • Choose the USB flash drive

#### 2 — Install Ubuntu

Install Ubuntu normally, HOWEVER, if you elect to encrypt the installation, you will be required to enter a password every time you boot. Unfortunately, the keyboard on the EeeBook will not work until after Ubuntu has started to boot. Therefore, encrypting the entire drive is "a bad idea" unless you always have an external keyboard nearby.

#### 3 — Caveats

There are some hardware issues that you will need to be aware of. I have not used an EeeBook in 5+ years so do not know if any of the items below are still problems or not. If they are, be prepared to do some post-installation investigation.

- the Bluetooth radio is uses the Broadcom BCM43341B0 chipset. This was not part of the default Ubuntu installation when I last installed it on an EeeBook in 2014
- the audio device has a 50/50 chance of working
- the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys for brightness may not work consistently, going from full brightness to off with a single tap
- the keyboard will not work until the login screen — or unless you are in BIOS mode — so have an external USB keyboard nearby if you ever have to do recovery work on the device
- keep your expectations low
  ⇢ This particular netbook shipped with [a quad-core Atom Z3735F processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80274/intel-atom-processor-z3735f-2m-cache-up-to-1-83-ghz.html) which was sluggish at the best of times. Do not expect a great deal of performance when working with modern websites, watching videos with resolutions higher than 720p, or doing anything that requires a good degree of I/O work

Comment: Thank you Matigo. I followed your instructions to the letter, but it still doesn't boot. In "Boot Override" I have "USB Entry for Windows To Go", "Windows Boot Manager" and "Grub2Win EFI - 32 Bit". I selected the USB. I goes back to the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Format the USB stick as FAT

Right Click Ubuntu ISO Image and select "Open With Disk Image Mounter"

ISO image will be mounted

Copy the files in the mounted image to the USB stick, some files cannot be copied, skip them. They are in a linked directory.

Add bootia32.efi to /EFI/BOOT/ folder in the stick

Unmount the USB and use it to boot your Eeebook

You can use this bootia32.efi :
https://www60.zippyshare.com/v/PCuPE9hL/file.html

This is not for bounty, just to make a child happy :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on it. I got stuck with gnome-disk-image-mounter. When I right-click on the iso and choose this option, something opens and then shuts down very quickly. I tried the command line but I was not sure of the syntax. When I typed "sudo gnome-disk-image-mounter --writable lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso /dev/sdc1" it returned with no message and nothing was done on my usb key.

Comment: Maybe you need to work with lubuntu 20.04 iso. I did so on my T100. Also it might or might not be automatically mounted.

Comment: I didn't find lubuntu 20.04 iso for 32 bits. Only amd64. I think the latest 32 bits was the one I have.

Comment: Ooops, it was mounted. 4 times. I saw it listed in "Devices" 4 times, then the pc crashed :). After reboot, I see nothing in the "open with" options. Anyway, I had a copy of the files "inside" the .iso, so I'm using these.

Comment: 64 bit iso might work for you too, anyways, let's wee what happens.

Comment: Hurray, I got something new! GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2 - "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completion". Then the command prompt "grub>". I did a TAB and I have "boot" in the options. Shall I type that?

Comment: I really don't know much about GRUB. Also I am really curious if the modified İSO boots your EeeBook.