# Are these instructions safe?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

This is a follow-up of my previous question, here:
[How to boot lubuntu from a live usb on an EeeBook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318120/how-to-boot-lubuntu-from-a-live-usb-on-an-eeebook)

I found a long list of instructions here:
https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md

I don't know if this is going to save my notebook or if this is a case of "too good to be true".
I can try to follow these instructions but I don't understand them.

I don't like the sound of the warning at the top : "add required dependencies; set grub to commit before make failures occurred". And anyway, I have no idea what "set grub to commit" means. AFAIK, grub is the boot loader used in cases of dual-boots and "to commit" means to save some unfinished code in the cases where several developers are working on the same program. As I'm on my own - except for your help - why would I need to "commit" anything, why can't I just save or backup? What am I supposed to commit????? Why and how should I use grub to do it???????? Why does typing "make" always result in error messages?

And the rest is no better. Why should I need a live CD to install on a notebook that doesn't have a CD drive? Am I supposed to plug in an external CD drive?

Comment: Does it have USB ports?

Comment: That link seems very much like overkill for what you are trying to achieve. You will have to download the ISO file, and "burn it" to a DVD or USB, and then boot from that. There is a nice, step by step, guide here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it has 2 usb ports. I've got the iso and the sha256sum is OK.

Comment: With the new USB stick it doesn't boot either... Not with the regular method anyway. I can set the notebook to boot from it but it just goes back to the BIOS, with or without "secure boot" enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions for booting form a dvd/cd/usb drive look safe, but for getting the usb/dvd (cd wont fit) ready, I don't trust it. You can just back up your data, install rufus (rufus.ie) if you are on windows, create a boot drive from the ISO from the official Ubuntu/Lubuntu website (no github) and use the boot and install part of the instructions you linked. Just make sure you install GRUB to your hard disk/ssd, and not to the usb stick.

You don't have to "commit" something, a backup (in iso form) will be everything you need in case you need to go back. You can even make an iso backup in the live usb session.

DVD's are pretty slow, and Ubuntu will not fit on CD's. I recommend using an usb stick (min 4 GB right now) so you don't have to plug in an external CD/DVD player/writer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I've got 2 bootable usb keys, one with lubuntu from the official repo, and one with this iso. This <self-censorship> machine won't boot from any of them.